# Why does grouping by blank strings ignore length in Snowflake/Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, group-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-redshift

Imagine you have a query:
`SELECT table.blank_names FROM table GROUP BY table.blank_names`

In this case, `blank_names` is a column of blank strings of various lengths (' ' of length 1, '   ' of length 3, etc.).

Why in Redshift and Snowflake does this query only return 1 row? If you remove the `GROUP BY` the query returns the number of rows in the table.

BigQuery operates differently. If you assume `blank_names` has blank strings of `x` different lengths, the query will return `x` rows.

Does anyone know how I can workaround this or why this is the behavior?

The details explain what I tried and what I was expecting.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You might receive a better response at: [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi did you check how many rows get when you do Select Distinct blank_names ?

Comment: You get 2 rows, a null row and a row with an empty string

Answer (score 0):

> Why in Redshift and Snowflake does this query only return 1 row? If
> you remove the GROUP BY the query returns the number of rows in the
> table.

This is not how grouping works in Snowflake. If you have blank strings or strings with only spaces (based on your example), they will form separate groups:

```
with X as
(
  select 1 as VAL, '' as STR1 
  union all
  select 2, ' '
  union all
  select 3, '  '
)
select sum(VAL) as SUM_VAL from X group by STR1
;
```

| SUM_VAL |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Comment: Sorry I got confused, this is just a problem for Redshift